# multiple page titles with one header file

Tags: php, html, css, header, include

i have one file for the header which is included on all of my other pages. I was wondering how i could have different page titles for with the same page header. I am using PHP and MySql. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the title in a variable e.g.

```
$title = 'Main title';
if($page == 'this page has a different title') {
  $title = 'A different title';
}
include 'header.php';
```

In header.php set

```
<head>
  <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
...
```

Answer (score 6):

On every specific page, add `$pgName = 'Page Title';` to title each page. Then after this code, `include()` the header as normal. In the header file, add this in the `<head>` tags:

```
<title><?php if(isset($pgName) && is_string($pgName)){echo $pgName;}else{echo 'Default title';} ?></title>
```

Answer (score 1):

break out the title tag from the include and place it in page, seems to be forcing you to make workarounds